# DB_NAME() in SQL Server when using [DBName].[SchemaName].[TblName] query syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

The following query returns the name of the current database:

```
USE [DB1]
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Current_DB
FROM [dbo].[TblName]
```

**Result:**

```
Current_DB
----------
DB1
```

I'm seeing very strange results when using `DB_NAME()` with queries that SELECT FROM a table in `[DBName].[SchemaName].[TblName]` notation:

**T-SQL**

```
USE [DB1]
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Current_DB
FROM [DB1].[dbo].TblName
UNION
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Current_DB
FROM [DB2].[dbo].TblName
UNION
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Current_DB
FROM [DB3].[dbo].TblName
UNION
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Current_DB
FROM [DB4].[dbo].TblName
```

**Result:**

```
Current_DB
----------
DB1
```

**T-SQL**

```
USE [DB1]
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Current_DB
FROM [DB1].[dbo].TblName
UNION ALL
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Current_DB
FROM [DB2].[dbo].TblName
UNION ALL 
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Current_DB
FROM [DB3].[dbo].TblName
UNION ALL
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Current_DB
FROM [DB4].[dbo].TblName
```

**Result:**

```
Current_DB
----------
DB1
DB1
DB1
...  (632,788 rows of DB1 !!!)
```

Even if I omit the `USE [DB1]` from T-SQL query, I get the same results - the database selected in the Query Target dropdown menu of SSMS is the one appearing in the results.

How can I get the correct `DB_NAME()` across multiple queries using `[DBName].[SchemaName].[TblName]` format?

Comment: As you said `returns the name of the current database`. Not the database of the table(s) in the FROM clause.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? you already know the db name when you use [DB1].[dbo].TraceContactSource

Comment: You can't. The only way to get `DB_NAME()` to return the name you want is to do `use [dbname]` first. And if you can do that, you already have the name...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DB_NAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) without parameter shows the database name of the currently connected session, not the underlying database of the object you are querying.

From the docs:

> A. Returning the current database name. This example returns the name
>   of the current database.
>
> SELECT DB_NAME() AS [Current Database];

Otherwise what would you expect if you do a join between databases and call `DB_NAME()`?

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME() -- ??
FROM
    Database1.dbo.Table1 AS T
    CROSS JOIN Database2.dbo.Table2 AS N
```

You can switch connected databases with the `USE <DatabaseName>` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DB_NAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function returns the name of the *current database* if the `database_id` argument is not specified.

*current database* does not mean the database where the table you are querying lives, but the database you are currently connected to.

The difference between the `union` and the `union all` queries is that `union` returns distinct values - and since you are selecting the same value in every query, a single value is returned.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the UNION ALL is returning 632,788 even though only 4 queries are UNION ALL'd ?

Comment: Yes - there are a total of  632,788 rows in all the tables combined. If you where to do `(select count(*) from table1) + (select count(*) from table2)` and so on that's the number you would get.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! :)

Answer (score 0):

`DB_NAME()` returns the name of the database you are currently connected to. A query can reference multiple databases in the `FROM`, so what would expect for a query like?

```
SELECT DB_NAME()
FROM DB1.dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN DB2.dbo.OtherTable OT ON OT.ID = YT.ID;
```

For your query, you need to specify the name of the database in your query:

```
USE [DB1]
SELECT N'DB1' AS Current_DB
FROM [DB1].[dbo].TraceContactSource
UNION ALL
SELECT N'DB2' AS Current_DB
FROM [DB2].[dbo].TraceContactSource
UNION ALL 
SELECT N'DB3' AS Current_DB
FROM [DB3].[dbo].TraceContactSource
UNION ALL
SELECT N'DB4' AS Current_DB
FROM [DB4].[dbo].TraceContactSource
```

As per the comments, however, if you're actually after a list of (non-system) databases, perhaps this achieves your goal:

```
SELECT [name] AS Current_DB
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4;
```

Comment: Unless adding records from the actual tables, the `from` clause is redundant - you can simply do `SELECT N'DB1' As Current_Db UNION ALL SELECT N'DB2'  UNION ALL SELECT N'DB3'`...

Comment: Infact, `SELECT [name] AS Current_Db FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4;` might be better, depending on their goal, @ZoharPeled, depending on their goal.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this without hard-coding the DB name in the query - I am using sp_executesql and running this code across 100+ db's to create a comparison report. I have found a way to do this now... thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sounds like what we had here was an XY problem, @Adam .